# make textbox value to datetime

Tags: windows-phone-7, datetime

Maybe this is to simple. If I have a textbox where I want to input a numeric value like "1300" and make it to display like datetime like this "13:00".

So what you should see is only 13:00 but it's also the days date.

anyone understand my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need to use [Day or Time Picker](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-datepicker-and-timepicker-in-depth--api-and-customization). This is most common way for Windows Phone to display date and time. 
 
Check also [Making a DateTimePicker](http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/Silverlight-Making-a-DateTimePicker.aspx) 
and [Windows Phone 7 - DatePicker and TimePicker](http://www.dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=172)

But if you want to use only `TextBox`, you need to handled `TextBox.LostFocus=OnLostFocus`

```
    private void OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //here change text of TextBox however you want.
    }
```

**UPD**

If you want to place current time to `TextBox` as default value you can to use

```
  tb.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
```

when you arrive to current page or when `TextBox.GotFocus=OnGotFocus`

```
    private void OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       tb.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(); 
    }
```

**UPD2**

When in `TextBox` you have value (for example 1300) you need to parse it and get `newHours` hours and `newMinutes` minutes. Then

```
 var today = DateTime.Now;
 var newDate = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, newHours, newMinutes, 0);
```

Comment: Can I add the datetime.now() but the value you write in the textbox is the time.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully understand you comment, but I try to response. See updated answer.

Comment: Almost what I am looking for but I will try to explain again. If I input the value 1300. I want this value to be the time in datetime and the date should be the date of the day. =)

Comment: You should parse it, when you need DateTime variable (for example on LostFocus).

Comment: example, how to parse string? or other kind. Provide correct comment, pls

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28812/discussion-between-alexander-mogren-and-jimpanzer)